# Select TreeView node by text

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a TreeView where I get nodes like:

```
TreeNode tn = parent.Nodes[indexProject].Nodes[currDesign].Nodes
```

This is legacy data from old project so I know indexing is bad practice for tree views.

That I want to know is if  there is any way to select node by `Text`, I mean, code above returns something like this in last node:

[image]

So I want to get Node who contains `FBOM` in text field is it possible to do something like:

```
TreeNode tn = parent.Nodes[indexProject].Nodes[currDesign].Nodes.where(x => x.Text.Contains("FOB"))
```

I also try :

```
 TreeNode tn = (TreeNode)parent.Nodes[indexProject].Nodes[currDesign].Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>()
                                    .Where(r => r.Text.Contains("FBOM"));
```

But I get:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode]' to type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode'.'

Answer (score 0):

If you tree view is not the immediate child, you might have to flatten it a bit. For example,

```
 var result = treeView1.FlattenTree().Cast<TreeNode>()
                                    .Where(r => r.Text == "Node3");
```

Where FlattenTree is defined as.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> FlattenTree(this TreeView source)
    {
        return FlattenTree(source.Nodes);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> FlattenTree(this TreeNodeCollection source)
    {
        return source.Cast<TreeNode>().Concat(source.Cast<TreeNode>().SelectMany(x => FlattenTree(x.Nodes)));
    }
}
```

Considering there is a possibility that there might be duplicate nodes with same text, a collection is returned in above. You can alter the linq to suit you requirements though.

Comment: And what if I want to do result.Nodes.Add? How can I achieve that?

Comment: in the result treeview, you want to retain the hierarchy structure ?

Comment: Yes I want same hierarchy